# How can I recommend my Flutter app when I want to open a map from Messenger?

Tags: flutter, fluttermap, flutter-deep-link

my English may be bad.

DESCRIPTION OF PROBLEM
I have a trucking app. There is a map installed to select the point of departure and the point of receipt of the cargo. The bottom line is that I want to parse geolocation from messengers (such as whatsapp, telegram). How can I make my application appear in the "Open with" and "Share With" lists? help me please. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caiOO.jpg)

I found a solution with [uni_links: ^0.5.1](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links) for Android but I couldn't find a solution for IOS.